# IE10 Adobe Flash Rendering

Tags: internet-explorer

Does any one knows how IE 10 renders a flash content using inbuilt activx control flash.ocx provided along with Microsoft updates?

Rendering I meant.. displaying... which api is used for displaying the flash content after decoding.